# Samsung galaxy s4 - how do i find out what my phone is locked to?

Tags: samsung-galaxy-s-4, sim-unlocking

I have recently purchased a Samsung galaxy s4 off of eBay but when it arrived it did not have any indication of what network it belonged to, every time I have gone on websites and typed in the coding to get the iem number it just says it  does not belong to any network at the moment
where do i find out what network my phone belongs to?
thank you

Comment: I assume that you've tried it with your SIM and confirmed that it is carrier-locked?  Try going to Settings -> About and add the specific model number and build number to this post.

Answer (score 0):

try a Samsung Galaxy S4 code:

- `*#7465625#`  View Phone Lock Status
- `*7465625*638*#` Configure Network Lock MCC/MNC
- `*7465625*782*#` Configure Network Lock NSP
- `#7465625*638*#` Insert Network Lock Keycode

Have fun!